# ExtJS submit form to download file

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

Having a really hard time figuring this out.  I need to submit a form in an ExtJS application and then download the data in a .CSV file.  The problem is, the way ExtJS has me submitting the form with "isUpload" the parameters I'm POSTing are being sent as "mulitpart/form-data" and I can't consume them or parse them.  I have multiple values of the same input field name.

```
field: A
field: B
field: C
```

When I submit for my grids they go over as multiple instances like above.  As soon as I introduce "isUpload" to the form they go overs as:

```
field: A,B,C
```

My program reads field as "A,B,C" and not three separate instances of field!

Here's my code.  Interesting that when I examine in Firebug the Params tab looks correct, but the POST tab has then all in one value.

I just recently added the parameters to the url to try and fake it out!

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/cgi-bin/cgijson007.pgm' + '?' + parameters,
        form : myForm,
        params : parameters,
        standardSubmit : true,
        isUpload : true
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isUpload: true only defines that you want to upload a file along with fields, so multipart is correct. To download I recommend you to use a hidden frame. For that use a helper defined within a Namespace.

```
helper.util.HiddenForm = function(url,fields){
    if (!Ext.isArray(fields))
        return;
    var body = Ext.getBody(),
        frame = body.createChild({
            tag:'iframe',
            cls:'x-hidden',
            id:'hiddenform-iframe',
            name:'iframe'
        }),
        form = body.createChild({
            tag:'form',
            cls:'x-hidden',
            id:'hiddenform-form',
            action: url,
            target:'iframe'
        });

    Ext.each(fields, function(el,i){
        if (!Ext.isArray(el))
            return false;
        form.createChild({
            tag:'input',
            type:'text',
            cls:'x-hidden',
            id: 'hiddenform-' + el[0],
            name: el[0],
            value: el[1]
        });
    });

    form.dom.submit();

    return frame;
}

// Use it like
helper.util.HiddenForm('my/realtive/path', [["fieldname","fieldValue"]]);
```

If the server answer with a download the save window will popup.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.  This forum is so much better than the ExtJS forums!  I am going to try the code you post.  I'm hopeful I can throw my params variable into your statement.

Comment: Is there a way for me to "gather up" the form fields and values?  What I have done already is a variable called "parameters" and it's value looks something like this:  

field=AS41F1MH.AFF&fieldid=AFF&type=CHAR&text=AFFILIATE&file=MMDF/AS41F1MH AS AS41F1MH&field=DIGITS(AS41F1MH.SSN)&fieldid=SSN&type=NUMERIC&text=SSN&field=AS41F1MH.NAME&fieldid=NAME&type=CHAR&text=NAME&format=CSV

Comment: @MichaelHaston This is really quick `var sets = str.split('&'),
 i = 0,
 kvSets = [];
 len = sets.length;
for (;i < len; i++) {
 kvSets.push(sets[i].split('='));
}`  use kvsets as arguement.

Comment: Sorry for the caps but ... YOU GUYS ARE AWESOME!  Been trying to work around this for longer than I care to admit!  Thank you both.

Comment: @MichaelHaston Both? You are just talking to one ;) and if the answer is correct you should mark it as answer and consider a upvote. The more upvotes you got or questions you mark as answered the more reputation you got yourself. Which means more privileges.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the original answer was a different user.  Thank you.  I'll mark this as answered.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I handler a post download on a grid listing:

First, I create html form container with hidden filed contains the parameters to post, and also a submit function.

```
var txtFileId = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Hidden', { name: 'fid', value: 0 });
var dwFrm = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
  autoEl: { tag: 'form',  method: 'POST', target: '_BLANK', 
    action: '/download/files' }, style: { hidden: true },
  items: [txtFileId, {
    xtype: 'hidden', name: 'userId', value: '1111'
  }],
  submit: function (fid) {
    if (fid) {
      txtFileId.setValue(fid);
      this.el.dom.submit();
    }
  }
});
```

Second, I dock the above component into grid's toolbar

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  .....
  dockedItems: [Ext.create("Ext.Toolbar", {
    dock: "top", items: [
      dwFrm, 
      { text: "Download Selected",
        handler: function () {
          var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
          if (!sm.hasSelection()) return null;
          var recs = sm.getSelection();
          dwFrm.submit(recs.data.id);
        }
      }
    ]
  })]
  .....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. Arrays included.

```
downloadFile: function (url, params) {
        debugger;
        var body = Ext.getBody(),
            frame = body.createChild({
                tag: 'iframe',
                cls: 'x-hidden',
                id: 'hiddenform-iframe',
                name: 'iframe'
            }),

            form = body.createChild({
                tag: 'form',
                method: 'POST',
                cls: 'x-hidden',
                id: 'hiddenform-form',
                action: url,
                target: 'iframe'
            });

        for (var i in params) {

            if (Ext.isArray(params[i])) {
                for (var j = 0; j < params[i].length; j++) {
                    form.createChild({
                        tag: 'input',
                        type: 'hidden',
                        cls: 'x-hidden',
                        id: 'hiddenform-' + i,
                        name: i,
                        value: params[i][j]
                    });
                }
            } else {

                form.createChild({
                    tag: 'input',
                    type: 'hidden',
                    cls: 'x-hidden',
                    id: 'hiddenform-' + i,
                    name: i,
                    value: params[i]
                });
            }

        }

        form.dom.submit();

        return frame;
    }
```